# EWS api - update ContactsGroup display name

Tags: c#, outlook, exchangewebservices

I am struggling to rename the ContactsGroup in the outlook using EWS api. I have a method to rename the group:

```
    public bool ChangeGroupName(string oldGroupName, string newGroupName)
    {
        bool result = false;
        var folder = FindFolderByName(_folderName);
        if (folder == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        ContactGroup group = FindGroupByName(oldGroupName, folder.Id);
        if (group != null)
        {
            group.DisplayName = newGroupName;
            group.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
        }
        result = (FindGroupByName(newGroupName, folder.Id) != null);
        return result;
    }
```

and method to find the group:

```
public ContactGroup FindGroupByName(string groupName, FolderId folderId)
{
    ItemView groupView = new ItemView(10);
    SearchFilter groupClassFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "IPM.DistList");
    SearchFilter groupNameFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ContactGroupSchema.DisplayName, groupName);
    SearchFilter groupFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And) { groupClassFilter, groupNameFilter };

    FindItemsResults<Item> groupFindResult = _service.FindItems(folderId, groupFilter, groupView);

    if (groupFindResult.Items.Count == 1)
    {
        var group = (ContactGroup)groupFindResult.Items[0];
        ContactGroup contactGroup = ContactGroup.Bind(_service, group.Id);
        return contactGroup;
    }
    return null;
}
```

After i rename the group - i cant find it anymore using the new name.

BUT if i use an old one - the group is there. In the properties it has new name as DiplayName and also in outlook it displays correctly but this FindGroupByName method cant find it. IsDirty equals to false. have anybody faced such an issue? is there some kind of a delay in the outlook servers(i waited for quite some time before the second call)? what can be the possible solution? or maybe there are some docs which might help?